# Какой вид сложного предложения?

Tags: синтаксис, сложное-предложение

Вы говорили:
 
Нам пора расстаться,
Что вас измучила
Моя шальная жизнь,
Что вам пора за дело приниматься,
А мой удел —
Катиться дальше, вниз.

Answer (score 1):

Сложное предложение, состоящее из 5 простых, с бессоюзной и союзной подчинительной связью.Три придаточных предложения между собой соединены однородной связью.

Answer (score 0):

Это сложное предложение с различными видами связи.

**(1) Вы говорили: (2)Нам пора расстаться, (3)Что вас измучила Моя шальная жизнь, (4)Что вам пора за дело приниматься, (5)А мой удел — Катиться дальше, вниз.**

Я полагаю, что предложения 2, 3, 4, 5 **однородны** между собой, так как  связаны с предложением 1 изъяснительными отношениями (все они  относятся к речи персонажа).

**Но оформление  несколько необычное,** так как предложения 3 и 4 имеют подчинительные союзы. Если их убрать, то это будет бессоюзная связь между 1 и 2, 3, 4, 5.

Вывод:

Но при наличии подчинительных союзов  мы имеем **совмещение бессоюзной   и подчинительной союзной   связи** между предложением 1 и   предложениями 2, 3, 4, 5.

Между собой предложения 2, 3, 4, 5 связаны **сочинительной бессоюзной и союзной связью** (союз А).

Answer (score 0):

> (1) *Вы говорили:*
>
> (2) *Нам пора расстаться,*
>
> (3) *Что вас измучила*
>
> *Моя шальная жизнь,*
>
> (4) *Что вам пора за дело приниматься,*
>
> *А мой удел —*
>
> *Катиться дальше, вниз*.

.

**По-моему, возможен такой разбор:**

сложноподчинённое предложение с тремя однородными придаточными — 2, 3 и 4;

в первом придаточном (предложение 2) опущен союз "что";

третье придаточное (предложение 4) представляет собой сложносочинённое предложение.